# how to use EKEvent?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, c, ios4

```
NSDictionary *d = (NSDictionary *) [arrGarden objectAtIndex:0];
    int intarrCount=0;

    NSString *strDate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [d valueForKey:@"open_date_for_calendar"]];

    NSArray *arrDateList =[strDate componentsSeparatedByString:@","];


    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];



    for(int i=0;i<[arrDateList count];i++)
    {
        intarrCount++;
        EKEventStore *eventDB = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

        EKEvent *myEvent  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventDB];

        NSString *trimmedString = [[arrDateList objectAtIndex:i] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
      //  NSString *trimmedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrDateList objectAtIndex:i] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];

        myEvent.title     = [d valueForKey:@"garden_name"];
        myEvent.startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:trimmedString];
        //myEvent.endDate   = [dateFormatter dateFromString:trimmedString];
        myEvent.endDate  = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:0 sinceDate:myEvent.startDate];
        myEvent.allDay = YES;

        [myEvent setCalendar:[eventDB defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
        NSError *err;
        [eventDB saveEvent:myEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
        //NSString *eID = myEvent.eventIdentifier;


    if(intarrCount == [arrDateList count])
    {
        if (err == noErr) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Event Added to your calendar"
                                  message:nil
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }
    }
    }
```

above my line of code that i used..

when i add event to calendar the event add successfully in calendar but after 10-15 seconds the events are removed automatically...
please help me where i have mistake in line of code
thanks....

Comment: please check your end date. you add timeinterval 0. so maybe it removes that.

Comment: i also change it but that cant work...

Answer (score 5):

This code is use for add the Event.

```
-(IBAction)eventAddToiCal:(id)sender
    {

        if(txtTitle.text.length == 0)
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Enter Data" message:@"Please enter data into fields" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil ];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }
        else 
        {
            event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
            event.startDate = startDate; 
            event.title = txtTitle.text;
            event.location = txtLocation.text;
            event.endDate = endDate;
            event.notes = txtvNote.text;

            /// tejas (Save Event in default Calendar of iPhone)
            // Try to save the event

            [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
            NSError *error = nil;
            [self.eventsList addObject:event];
            [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
        }
    }
```

Comment: defaultCalendarForNewEvents is what just fixed my problem.  Thank you.  Totally not in the doc.  And I wanted to point out to the OP not to allocate the EKEventStore inside the loop.  It's hella slow.  Just a thing.